# Is there any maximum age limit to start learning the Vedas?

Tags: vedas

What is the maximum age (if any) to start learning the Vedas?

I heard somewhere that one must start it at a good age so that they can learn their full Shakha but also so he can get married at a good age.

Would 19 be considered late? (If one starts at 19, my guess is that it would take 10 years to learn my Shakha (KYV Taittiriya), so at 29 they would finish, give or take 2 years.)

Please correct me if I have made any errors in my question body.

Comment: there is a maximum age for upanayana - 16 for brahmins, 24 for vaishyas. idk any such limit for learning vedas because you're allowed to study all 4 vedas (after learning your own first), and that can take 12x4 = 48 years.